# autoResizingMask and animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use autoResizingMask in my tableView in LeftMenu VC and it works good if I drag table to gap - it resizing well, but then I let go my tableView and it goes to normal size I have no animation of resizing bounds - tableView just takes its normal bounds. How can I animate it?

I fix cells with

```
cell.textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

but it not works with searchBar. searchBar is in header. how fix it?

Comment: The "xcode" tag should only be used for questions about Xcode itself, and not for general iOS programming topics.

Comment: Additionally, I see no code in this question (or periods for that matter), please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered same behaviour while using
https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController

Then I found that there in method named "panGestureRecognizerDidRecognize", which is forcing tableView to resize automatically by adjusting offset value.

For your case it may be different, try to adjust width of your tableView once animation is finished.

Comment: I fix cells with     cell.textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
 but it not works with searchBar. Do your have searchBar?

Comment: I am not using searchBar